# Filter Authentication message using Serilog on Azure

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, serilog

I need to filter the following message on Azure using Serilog:
**AuthenticationScheme: BasicAuthentication was successfully authenticated.** The message is Information level.

In the below code I put everything I tried so far, and am still getting those logs.
I am using .net 6 in asp.net project.

```
public static void Configure(WebApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            if(builder is null)
                return;

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .Enrich.WithProcessId()
                .Enrich.WithProcessName()
                .Enrich.WithThreadId()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .WriteTo.Async(x => x.Logger((configureLogger) =>
                {
                    configureLogger.Filter.ByExcluding(logEvent => 
                        logEvent.MessageTemplate.Text.ToLower().Contains("authenticationscheme: basicauthentication") &&
                        logEvent.Level < LogEventLevel.Warning);
                    configureLogger.WriteTo.Async(consoleConfiguration =>
                    {
                        consoleConfiguration.Console(new ExpressionTemplate(
                            template: "{@l:w4}: {SourceContext}\n" +
                                      "{#if Scope is not null}" +
                                      "\t{#each s in Scope}=> - {s}{#delimit} {#end}\n" +
                                      "{#end}" +
                                      "{@m}\n",
                            theme: TemplateTheme.Code));
                    });
                }))
                .CreateBootstrapLogger();

            builder.WebHost.UseSerilog();
        }
```

In local this works perfect. When the I log an information like this:

```
logger.LogInformation("AuthenticationScheme: BasicAuthentication".ToUpper());
```

the filter is applied in local, but not on Azure.
Any idea?
thnx

Comment: Hmm.. Have you tried added package [Serilog.Sinks.AzureApp](https://github.com/cnelsonakgov/serilog-sinks-azureapp/blob/master/src/Serilog.Sinks.AzureApp/Sinks/AzureApp/AzureAppSink.cs) or including AzureWebAppDiagnostics via the builder `builder.Logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics()`. The latter requires adding reference to Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

Comment: Yes, I tried, and not resolved my issue

Answer (score 1):

Using *Serilog.Expressions*:

```cs
   .Filter.ByExcluding("@m like '%AuthenticationScheme: BasicAuthentication%' ci")
```

Comment: why not like and not like for exclude?!

Comment: Typo'd - fixed now 